# Is there a way to have SQL work in parallelism with two computers?

Tags: postgresql, parallelism

Amateur here. I have a couple of the same old 4 core computers that I am trying to use to beef up some automatic query scripts that run every evening for my hobby. I recently found MPICH to have the two computers communicate with each other.  I also found documentstion that allows postresql to use more than the default number of cores (It was set at 2). I am hoping there is some way of being able to use all 8 cores to run some SQL queries.  Is this possible? Any thoughts or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Check **[Postgres-XL](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgres-xl/)**.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ setting up this beast on "a couple of the same old 4 core computers" might become a full-scale hobby in itself, don't you think?

Comment: @mustaccio sounds kinda cool to me! Better that than being mindlessly sat in front of a television or drinking yourself silly every evening!  To the OP, come back if you have problems! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @mustaccio you are absolutely right but it does answer the question. If I posted an answer, there would be a notice or something about the extra work needed (compared to a Postgres installation).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution using plain PostgreSQL, you will have to use *sharding*, that is, you will have to split the database into parts that you keep on different machines.

You can use [PL/Proxy](https://plproxy.github.io/) to have a single query run on all machines in parallel.